# Spring Boot: use property from application.properties in log4j2.xml

Tags: logging, spring-boot

I have several copies of the same WAR running on the same server. I'd like to configure a different set of log files for each of them by specifying a prefix in `application.properties`. Cannot figure out how to resolve this value in `log4j2.xml`. The lookups `sys` and `env` are global and not suitable. Tried to make `ctx` work by adding the prefix to ThreadContext but cannot seem to do it early enough to get picked up.

Is this possible somehow?

application.properties:

```
logfile.prefix=xyz
```

log4j2.xml:

```
<rollingfile name="file" filename="${sys:app.root}/logs/${???:logfile.prefix}-sm.log" 
filepattern="${sys:app.root}/logs/${???:logfile.prefix}-sm-%i.log.gz">
...
</rollingfile>
<rollingfile name="file" filename="${sys:app.root}/logs/${???:logfile.prefix}-db.log" 
filepattern="${sys:app.root}/logs/${???:logfile.prefix}-db-%i.log.gz">
...
</rollingfile>
... more appenders similar to these, with different filenames
```